# use the cmd command result in case statment

Tags: vb.net, windows, shell, cmd, case

im trying to get the windows license status from cmd by running this code

```
    Dim oProcess As New Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", " /c cscript ""%windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs"" /xpr | findstr ""The machine""")
    oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    oStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden


    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

    End Using

    TextBox4.Text = sOutput

    Select Case sOutput
        Case Is = "The machine is permanently activated."
            TextBox4.Text = "activated"



    End Select
```

the code is working okay but the result that appears on my textbox4 is : The machine is permanently activated. i need to take this result to case statement

```
Select Case sOutput
        Case Is = "The machine is permanently activated."
            TextBox4.Text = "activated"
```

all i need if i get The machine is permanently activated. status from cmd then show in textbox4 word ( activated )

Comment: Why are you invoking cmd to invoke cscript? It would make more sense imho to directly invoke cscript. I'd guess there could be a line break which you are missing in your `Case`

Comment: Is that the exact and only output you get? Try `Select Case sOutput.Trim()` to remove any leading or trailing spaces/line breaks.

Comment: use visual-vincent it's the exact code but i need to take the result from sOutput to case  statement  and if result = activated show word ( yes ) in textbox4 , if result = unactivated show word ( no ) in textbox4

Comment: thanx  Visual Vincent u are my hero <3 it's working

Comment: Glad I could help, again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the output contains a space or a line break at the end. Call [**`Trim()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) on the string to remove any leading or trailing spaces and/or line breaks.

```vb
Select Case sOutput.Trim()
```